# How to change spacing in a template?

Tags: spacing

I am trying to write a two column biological review using a downloaded template. I had to add few pictures(one column) in between. So to adjust the spacing the template generates spacing in some places which are not appropriate. Does anybody know how to change spacing in it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question in its current form is extremely vague and hard to answer, normally in this cases, you would provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) a short and concise piece of code that exhibits the issue you are experiencing. It would be really helpful to know what template you
re using, how you include pictures etc. (You might want to have look at the [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get acquainted with the format on this site.)